# Umbrella header not found.Could not build Objective C module. Swift and Objective Framework Interoperability

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a 2 frameworks.

Framework A- swift 
. and  Framework B - objective C

Framework A makes use of framework B

I want make use of Framework A in my application. I linked them asusual. 
When I try to use the framework class in Objective C file in the app or import it Swift file. It throws me with following error

**"Umbrella header  not found"
"Could not build Objective C module" for Framework B**
Umbrella header in that framework is public. Can anyone help me with this ?!

Whereas I am able to use the Framework B's class in Swift classes of my application  directly.

Comment: give more details like which frameworks you're using

Comment: Frameworks are internal to our organization. Tats why I mentioned with a generic name

Comment: As it is editable frameworks.. Instead of making it both different. try to combain the frameworks. and use it

Answer (score 0):

In app's build setting, the header path had paths specific to framework's headers. Once I removed those header paths pointing to the objective C framework, the issue is resolved.